# Set report Export Details preferences (Excel vs CSV)?

Tags: reporting, csv

When you Export Details in a report, it defaults to Excel. I don't use Excel, I always want csv. Is there a way to set the default or the preference?

[image: export details]

Comment: I seriously doubt it.

Comment: @AdrianLarson sad. I export all the time and it is like a splinter. Just annoying enough to try to fix. :)

Comment: I posted it in the SF ideas section. So it might happen in 10  years. - https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000E1urAAC

Comment: You could roll your own with the Analytics API if you don't care about xls at all. Cost benefit analysis is up to you! I bet you could whip it together in a day or two.

Comment: @AdrianLarson yeah was hoping I wouldn't have to do that. :) According to xkcd I can only spend 2 hours on it. https://xkcd.com/1205/

Comment: Ha! I just linked to xkcd last night!